# background image missing in slides ionic rc 2

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic2

My intention is to have a slide with Background image but the Background image is missing in ion-slide.background image is working fine in other pages.the following is the code.......

```
typescript

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, MenuController, NavController } from 'ionic- angular';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
// import { RegistrationPage } from '../event-create/event-create';
import { LinkToRegistration } from '../about/about';
import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal';
import { UserData } from '../../providers/user-data/user-data';
 // import * as moment from 'moment';
 // import * as firebase from 'firebase';
 declare var firebase: any;
 export interface Slide {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  //image: string;
 }
@Component({
templateUrl: 'tutorial.html'
})
export class TutorialPage {
slides: Slide[];
showSkip = true;
public time: any[] = [];
amp = "";
count = 0;
aseats = 0;
gathering = 0;
start = 0;
sfix ="";
date = 0;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public menu: MenuController,
public modalCtrl: ModalController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public    userData: UserData) {
  //   this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
  var db = firebase.database();
 // var ref = db.ref("dcuser");
  var time = db.ref("dcsession details");

// date and time==================
  time.on("child_added", (snap)=>{
// this.count++;
// var active = db.ref('dcsession details/'+session+'/UserGroup);
    console.log("added:", snap.key);
    if(snap.val().SessionStatus == "Active")
    {   var session = snap.key;
        var active = db.ref('dcsession details/'+session+'/UserGroup');
       // ===================================================testing

          active.on('child_added', (spsnapshot) => {
          if(spsnapshot.val().UserSessionStatus == "Active")  
          {
               this.count++
          }
    }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
   // ==========================================================================testing
        console.log("sessionid:"+session);
        this.userData.setsession(session);
        this.time.push({date: snap.val().Date, start: snap.val().StartingTime, aseats: snap.val().AllottedSeats });
        this.aseats = snap.val().AllottedSeats;
        this.gathering = snap.val().GatheringCount;
        if(this.gathering == 1)
        {
          this.sfix = "st";
        }else if(this.gathering == 2)
        {
          this.sfix = "nd";
        }else if(this.gathering == 3)
        {
          this.sfix = "rd";
        }else
        {
          this.sfix = "th";
        }
        this.date = snap.val().Date;
        this.start = snap.val().StartingTime ;
      // var hours = this.start.getHours() % 12 || 12;  // 12h instead of 24h, with 12 instead of 0.
        this.amp = this.start >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        console.log("hor"+this.start);
        console.log("Date"+this.date);
        console.log("ampm"+this.amp);
        console.log("asets"+this.aseats);
    }

    console.log("time:",JSON.stringify(this.time));
 });

//     ==============================


this.slides = [
{
  title: '<b></b>',
  description: '<b> </b>',
  // image: 'assets/img/ica-slidebox-img-1.png',
}
];
 }
 presentModal() {
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
modal.present();
}
 dismiss() {
 this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}

startApp() {
  console.log("btton click detected");
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  this.navCtrl.push(LinkToRegistration);
}
onSlideChangeStart(slider) {
  this.showSkip = !slider.isEnd;
}
ionViewDidEnter() {
// the root left menu should be disabled on the tutorial page
  this.menu.enable(false);
}

 ionViewWillLeave() {
 // enable the root left menu when leaving the tutorial page
  this.menu.enable(true);
}
}
// modal content
```

scss file===========================================

```
.tutorial-page {
  .toolbar-background {
    background: #4795e2;
    border-color: transparent;
  }

.dcslide-img1{
     //background: url('../../img/Slides_slide1_WOdots.svg');
     //  background-color: blue;
    background: url('../assets/img/Slides_slide1_WOdots.svg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
  }
  .dcslide-img2{
    //background: url('assets/img/Slides_slide2_wWOdots.svg');
      background-color: blue;
   background: url('../assets/img/Slides_slide2_wWOdots.svg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }
  .dcslide-img3{
   // background: url('../../img/Slides_Slide3_WOdots.svg');
     background-color: blue;
     background: url('../assets/img/Slides_Slide3_WOdots.svg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;   
  }
  .dcslide-header-title{
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#a8d4ff;//#2975c0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-align: left;
  }
  .dcslide-aloava-value{
      font-size: 45px;
      color: #ffffff;//#044a8e;
      font-weight: bold;  
  }
  .dcslide-aloava-text{
      font-size: 15px;
      color:#FFEB3B;//#2975c0;
      text-transform: lowercase;
  }
  .dc-name{
    text-align:center; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-top: 40px;
    color:#ffffff
  }
  .dc-name-p{
    text-align:center;color:#003061;text-transform: lowercase;
  }
  .dcslide-badge{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .dcslide-heart-icon{
    color: #96ffa2;margin-right: 1px;margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .dcslide-pepole-icon{
    color: #ff4848;
    margin-right: -1px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 18px !important;
  }
  .card-header{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .slide-zoom {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .dc-count-panel{
        background-color: #0A6BC8;//rgb(150, 203, 255);//rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .slide-title {
    margin-top: 2.8rem;
  }

  .slide-image {
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 36px 0;
  }

    .image-holder {
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .image-holder:after {
        content:'';
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.7;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;

        background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
    }
    .image-holder:hover:after {
        opacity: 0;
    }
  //slide 2
  .item-inner{
        border-bottom: 0px solid #dedede;
  }
  ion-badge{
        padding: 1px 5px !important;
        background-color: #0a6bc8 !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
  }
  .hed-transparent{
   background: transparent !important;
  }
 .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination{
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 3px;
    width: 0;
 }
 .join-monthly-btn{
   margin: 0; 
   height: 5.6rem;
   font-size: 2rem;
   background-color: #044f78;
 }
 .dcslide-time{
   font-size: 55px;
   color: #ffffff;
 }
 .dcslide-ampm{
   color: #96cbff;
 }
 .dcslide-date{
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-left: -10px;
   color: #012548;
 }
  .fab-footer {
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .button-dark{
           color: #0a6bc8;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  .bar-footer {
    //background: url(../../img/footer-wireframe.png) repeat-x;
    height: 2px;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 44px;
    left: 0;
  }

  b {
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  p {
    padding: 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #60646B;

    b {
      color: #000000;
    }
  }


}
```

Html file ================================

```
<ion-header no-shadow>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-slides [options]="{pager: true}" (ionWillChange)="onSlideChangeStart($event)">
     <ion-slide class="dcslide-img1">   
      <ion-grid class="dc-count-panel">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-26>
             <div class="dcslide-header-title">
                 Creative's {{gathering}}{{sfix}} Monthly Gathering
             </div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-35>
              <div class="dcslide-aloava-value">{{aseats}}</div>
              <div class="dcslide-aloava-text">Allocated Seats</div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-35>
              <div class="dcslide-aloava-value animated infinite flash">{{ aseats-count }}</div>
              <div class="dcslide-aloava-text">Available Seats</div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>    
      <h3 class="dc-name">CREATIVES /  </h3>  
      <p class="dc-name-p">
         <ion-icon name="quote"></ion-icon> 
            WAS ESTABLISHED TO SPREAD AWARENESS ABOUT VARIOUS ARTS AND RAISE THE CEILING OF CREATIVITY AMONG CREATIVES IN .  
         <ion-icon name="quote"></ion-icon>
      </p>
      <button ion-button icon-only fab dark fab-bottom fab-center class="fab-footer" (click)="presentModal()">
        <ion-icon name="finger-print" is-active="false"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <div class="bar-footer"></div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide class="dcslide-img2">
      <ion-item class="hed-transparent">
          <ion-badge item-right> 
            <ion-icon name="people" class="dcslide-heart-icon" item-left></ion-icon> 
           {{ aseats-count }}/{{aseats}} </ion-badge>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide class="dcslide-img3">
     <ion-item class="hed-transparent">
          <ion-badge item-right> 
            <ion-icon name="people" class="dcslide-heart-icon" item-left></ion-icon> 
           {{ aseats-count }}/{{aseats}} </ion-badge>
      </ion-item>
     <br/><br/>
      <div class="dcslide-time">{{start}}
        <span class="dcslide-ampm">{{amp}}</span></div>
      <div class="dcslide-date">{{date| date:'EEE, MMMM dd'}}</div>
      <!--
      <div class="dcslide-date">{{date| date:'EEE, MMMM dd'}}</div>-->

      <ion-footer>
        <button ion-button icon-right block (click)="startApp()" class="join-monthly-btn">

          Join monthly gathering 
          <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </button> 
      </ion-footer>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the full img URL in CSS without any `../` , and check if that helps bring back the missing background image.

```
background: url('FULL URL');
```

Comment: sir,...i tried with **assets/img/imagename**.but its not working....same path is working fine with other pages..

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable with the path for background image under variables.scss and use the variable in whatever file you wish to use.

Variables.scss

```
$bg : "../assets/img/Slides_slide2_wWOdots.svg";
```

Your Scss file

```
.dcslide-img1{
    background: url($bg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```